# How to save the functional value and corresponding points when doing optimization in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am using `fminsearch` when doing optimization. My task is to save the points and corresponding functional values in each optimization to the workspace. For simplicity, assume I have the function to be optimized as follow:

`(4*x(1)^2+2*x(2)^2+x(1)*x(2)+2*x(2))`

I know how to define `OutputFcn` to save the points at each iteration, but I am not sure how to save the corresponding functional values in each optimization to the workspace. I write the codes as follow:

```
function [x,fval,history1,history2]=myproblem(x0)

 history1=[];
 history2=[];
 options=...
    optimset('OutputFcn',@CalibratedPointsInEachIteration,'Display','iter');
 [x,fval] = fminsearch(@objfun,x0,options);

 function stop = CalibratedPointsInEachIteration(x,optimValues,state)
     stop = false;
     if isequal(state,'iter')
       history1 = [history1; x];
       history2 = [history2; objfun(x)];
     end
 end

 function z = objfun(x)
   z =(4*x(1)^2+2*x(2)^2+x(1)*x(2)+2*x(2));
 end
end
```

However, it seems that the code above needs to recalculate the objective function at each iteration again before saving to `history2`. I wonder if I can simplify the codes further.

I want to save, not simply display each functional values on command window.

Comment: You don't need to recalculate `objfun(x)` at each iteration because its value is stored in `optimValues.fval`

Comment: @AVK, yes, should I write `history2 = [history2; objfun(x)]` to be `history2 = [history2; optimValues.fval]`?

Comment: Yes, you should. Also, it is better to avoid resizing `history1` and `history2` inside the output function as it may slow down the calculation.